# How does Bayes theorem apply to this question? Does it even apply?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Consider two coins: a regular fair coin and a two-headed one (i.e., both sides
are head). Pick a coin at random and toss it. If its top side shows a head, what is the
probability that the other side is also a head?

My understanding is that first we will calculate the probability of head using partitions. The probability of head given any outcome of the coin comes out to be **0.75**. Then, which probability we have to calculate further to answer this question. Do we have to apply conditional probability by finding the probability of two-headed coin given that head is selected. My answer comes out to be **0.6667**. Kindly help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the probability that the coin is the double header when given that it shows heads is $2/3$.$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(D\mid H)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(H\mid D)\,\mathsf P(D)}{\mathsf P(H\mid D)\,\mathsf P(D)+\mathsf P(H\mid S)\,\mathsf P(S)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{1/2}{1/2+1/4}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{2}{3}\end{align}$$Each individual face has the same chance to show and *two* from the *three* heads are on the double-headed coin.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the answer.